# Laravel Url generating issue

Tags: php, url, routes, laravel-5.3

When I put this

```
     <a href="{{ Route('admin.edit', $consignment->id )}}" >...</a>
```

I get this link: localhost:8000/dashboard/edit?3

I want to make the url like:  localhost:8000/dashboard/edit/3

What should I do ?
Would you please help me ?

Comment: Are you running nginx or apache?

Comment: I am using Xampp Server Apache

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while back before switching to nginx, when using apache it seemed I had lost my pretty urls, and I had to do two things to fix it. First create a `.htaccess` file in your `public/` directory and put this as the contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and the second thing was I had a `server.php` in my **project root folder** which I had to rename to `index.php` Without knowing all the details of your project its hard to determine what could be happening but this worked for me with the exact same issue. Best of luck